# Get Kubernetes FlexVolume Logs

Tags: logging, kubernetes, mounted-volumes

I'm trying to create a custom FlexVolume, but it's failing to attach/mount with a timeout message. Where can I find the logs to determine the cause of failure?

Here is my StatefulSet spec:

```
kind: StatefulSet
...
spec:
  ...
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      ...
      volumes:
        - name: "ignite-storage"
          flexVolume:
            driver: "co.mira/lvm"
            fsType: "ext4"
            options:
              awsRegion: "us-east-1"
              vols: "2"
              tag: "ignite"
              ebsType: "{{ ignite_storage_ebs_volume_type }}"
              sizeGb: "{{ ignite_storage_ebs_volume_size_gb }}"
              iopsPerGb: "2"
      containers:
        - name: ignite
          ...
          volumeMounts:
            - name: "ignite-storage"
              mountPath: "..."
```

My FlexVolume is deployed using a Daemon on all nodes at: /usr/libexec/kubernetes/kubelet-plugins/volume/exec/mira.co~lvm/lvm

Comment: can you share the command how you are attaching the `FlexVolume`?

Comment: sure. added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kube-controller-manager is responsible for attaching and detaching (if enabled), so look for logs to `attach`, `detach`, and `isattached` on the master at `/var/log/kube-controller-manager.log`. If it's deployed on its own kube-system pod, use: `kubectl -n kube-system logs -f $POD_NAME`.

For the operations `waitforattach`, `mountdevice`, `unmountdevice` check the kubelet logs on each of the nodes try `/var/log/kubelet.log` or `journalctl -u kubelet.service`.

`init` operations should be logged in both.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-storage/flexvolume.md#prerequisites)

The vendor and driver names must match flexVolume.driver in the volume spec, with '~' replaced with '/'.

While you have `driver: "co.mira/lvm"` and vendor name `mira.co~lvm`

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, but it doesn't answer my original question